# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) Reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, post, error-handling

I'm to post a form through a react form on my website but I face this error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
ContactMe.js:63 Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:16:1)
    at settle (settle.js:17:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (xhr.js:66:1)
```

this is the the server.js

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const path = require("path");
const contactRoute = require("./route/contactRoute");

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use("/", contactRoute);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
  app.get("*", (req, res) =>
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"))
  );
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, console.log(`server listing to port 5000 only`));
```

this is the contactRoute.js:

```
 const router = require("express").Router();
    const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
    
    router.post("/contact", (req, res) => {
      let data = req.body;
      if (
        data.name.length === 0 ||
        data.email.length === 0 ||
        data.message.length === 0
      ) {
        return res.json({ msg: "Please Fill All The Fields!" });
      }
    
      let smtpTransporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: "Gmail",
        port: 465,
        auth: {
          user: "here is my email",
          pass: "here is my password",
        },
      });
      let mailOptions = {
        from: data.email,
        to: "here is my email",
        subject: `message from ${data.name}`,
        html: `
                <h3>Informations<h3/>
                <ul>
                <li>Name: ${data.name}<li/>
                <li>Email: ${data.email}<li/>
                </ul>
                <h3>Message</h3>
                <p>${data.message}<p/>
                `,
      };
    
      
    
        smtpTransporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error) => {
        try {
          if (error)
            return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Please Fill All The Fields!" });
          return res.status(200).json({ msg: "Thank You For Contacting Mohammad." });
        } catch (error) {
          if (error) return res.status(500).json({ msg: "There is server error" });
        }
      });
    });
    module.exports = router;
```

I tried a lot of things but couldn't figure out the error can someone help please
Note:I found several similar questions on stack overflow but they were irrevelant or didn't work.